# Are there availability zones where AWS CodeBuild does not support VPCs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-codebuild

I am trying to restrict access to a load balancer to a fixed IP and to CodeBuild agents.  To that end, I want to add a security group rule that will prevent access to the load balancer unless traffic comes from the security group associated with the CodeBuild agents (as well as a separate security group rule that restricts access except from the fixed IP).  I think this means I need to associate CodeBuild with the VPC of the load balancer.

However, when I try to update an existing CodeBuild project using Terraform's [codebuild_project](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/codebuild_project.html) resourcce and configure the VPC like this:

```
vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = [var.codebuild_sg]
    subnets = var.public_subnet_ids
    vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}
```

where the variables are the security group to be used by CodeBuild, the subnets into which CodeBuild should be launched and the VPC, respectively, I get the following error message:

> Error updating CodeBuild project
>   (arn:aws:codebuild:eu-west-2:xxxxx:project/my-project):
>   InvalidInputException: CodeBuild currently doesn't support VPC in
>   eu-west-2c, please select subnets in other availability zones.

Are there some AZs for which CodeBuild does not support VPCs?  Or does this message mean something else?

Comment: Are you using a Windows container?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CodeBuild is not available in eu-west-2c. In eu-west-2 region, CodeBuild is only available in 2 AZs (eu-west-2a and eu-west-2b).

Comment: Have you got a link to any documentation that shows this?

Comment: Availability zone *labels* like `eu-west-2c` [are randomized](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ram/latest/userguide/working-with-az-ids.html) across AWS accounts and so do not necessarily refer to the same physical availability zone from one AWS account to the next. Thus it seems unlikely that this statement can be justified from the docs.

Comment: You are right Michael and for CodeBuild service account (where build hosts are provisioned) the 'eu-west-2(a/b/c)' always refers to the same physical AZ among which 'eu-west-2c' is not supported. Unfortunately I cannot back this up with any public documentation. OP can raise a case with AWS Support for confirmation.